# NSKeyedArchiver works on simulator but fails on tvOS device

Tags: objective-c, tvos, nskeyedarchiver

I'm archiving an object to a file - on simulator it works perfectly, but on a tvOS (Apple TV) device it doesn't (in other words `-(BOOL)archiveRootObject:toFile:` returns a funny `NO`):

```
static NSString * _DocumentsDirectory() {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentsDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return paths[0];
}
```

and:

```
NSString *fullPath = [_DocumentsDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:obj toFile:fullPath];
```

where `filename = @"foo.data"` and `obj` conforms to `NSCoding`.

I tried different ways to put together the path and different directories, but the result is the same.
The only thought I have is that there could be some writing permission I need to set.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating a bit, I found out that the only ways that Apple allows you to store data in tvOS apps are the following:

[image]

Therefore, I opted for using the Cache directory (which is purged only if space is needed) for data that I can eventually re-download, and NSUserDefaults for smaller data which I need to always access locally.